# Getting an sqlException when I run ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013

I made a method to get a scalar from a database using `ExecuteScalar` but it is throwing an exception. The SQL select statement looks correct to me. Can someone help me please.

The exact error I'm getting is

> Incorrect syntax near 'Invoices'.

Code:

```
public static String GetTotalBalanceDue() 
{
        decimal totalBalanceDue;

        string selectStatement =
            "SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal) " +
            "AS BalanceDue FROM Invoices" +
            "WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal > 0";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = PayablesDBConnection.GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection))
                {
                    totalBalanceDue = (decimal)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //exceptions are thrown to the controller, then to the view
            //Please make sure that do not use MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) in the DAL
            //because it couples the DAL with the view

            //throw is used instead of throw ex because the former preserves the stack trace
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return System.Convert.ToString(totalBalanceDue);
    }
```

I modified my select statement to be:

```
            string selectStatement =
                "SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal)" +
                "AS BalanceDue" +
                "FROM Invoices " +
                " WHERE vendorID =" + vendorID;
```

but I'm still getting

> Incorrect syntax near 'Invoices'.

Comment: i think its because your returning a recordset, not a scalar value.  
  
Invoice      Payment         Credit  
5                    5                    5  
6                     6                    6  
  
I am getting back  
  
BalanceDue  
15  
18

Comment: Wouldn't putting a sum in my select statement return a scalar value? Would you explain why it would return a recordset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify

```
 string selectStatement =
            "SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal) " +
            "AS BalanceDue FROM Invoices" +
            "WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal > 0";
```

TO:

```
string selectStatement =
            "   SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal) " +
            "   AS BalanceDue FROM Invoices" +
            "   WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal > 0";
```

Comment: Thanks adding the space before WHERE and FROM fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're returning a recordset, not a scalar

**UPDATE:** and also because you didnt have a space between your table name and the beginning of the where clause. i updated the example accordingly

As your query is written, it is going to return all Invoices that meet your criteria. So if you have 10 invoices with a TotalBalanceDue > 0, you are going to get 10 records back.

If you want to get a scalar value, you are going to have to constrain your query to one row. I am going to guess with an invoice ID

```
string selectStatement =
            "SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal) " +
            "AS BalanceDue FROM Invoices" +
            " WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal > 0 AND INVOICEID = " + InvoiceId.ToString();
```

Otherwise you are going to have to update your code to be able to accomodate multiple rows of results

try

```
public static String GetTotalBalanceDue() 
    {
        decimal totalBalanceDue;
        DataTable results = new DataTable();
        string selectStatement =
            "SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal) " +
            "AS BalanceDue FROM Invoices" +
            " WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal > 0";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = PayablesDBConnection.GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection))
                {
                     using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand))
{
    adapter.Fill(results);
}
                }
            }


        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //exceptions are thrown to the controller, then to the view
            //Please make sure that do not use MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) in the DAL
            //because it couples the DAL with the view

            //throw is used instead of throw ex because the former preserves the stack trace
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I fairly new to c#/visual studios but I don't see how initializing an SqlDataAdapter will affect code. The exact error I'm getting is "Incorrect syntax near 'Invoices'."

Comment: add a space before where. sorry didnt see your error message posted anywhere

 " WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymantTotal - CreditTotal > 0";

Comment: but after you add that space, what i posted is next on your list ;)

Comment: I added the space but getting the same error of "Incorrect syntax near 'Invoices'." . I noticed you removed my return statement. Was that intentional?

Comment: you added the space before where and are getting the same syntax error?

Comment: Here's my exact statement (Note I added Where vendorID = vendorID)                             string selectStatement =
                    "SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal)" +
                    "AS BalanceDue" +
                    "FROM Invoices " +
                    " WHERE vendorID =" + vendorID;

Comment: ..."AS BalanceDue " + "FROM Invoices " i added a space to the end of balance due. see a pattern emerging here?