# $id goes from a value to 0 for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio, dapper

I'm trying to do a POST with visual .Net (before it worked without any problem, and without warning it doesn't work correctly).

At the time of entering the repository, my class  "Expediente" brings the data successfully *(line 138 + window immediately)* where it is seen that the *ExpedienteId is = **26*** ... when I go past line 154 the fileId is **transformed to 0**

```
  public async Task<Expedientes> AgregarPrimerMovimiento(Expedientes expediente)
{
    using (var conexion = _baseProduccion.Conexion)
    {
        
        var sql =
              $"INSERT INTO Movimiento (ExpedienteId,FechaIngreso,SectorOrigen,SectorDestino,FechaEnvio) SELECT @ExpedienteId,@FechaCreacion,@TipoDocumentoId,@UltimoSector,@FechaModificacion";
           
        var parametrosExpediente = new
        {
            @ExpedienteId = expediente.ExpedienteId,
            @TipoDocumentoId = expediente.TipoDocumentoId.Value,
            @Descripcion = expediente.Descripcion,
            @FechaCreacion = expediente.FechaCreacion,
            @FechaModificacion = expediente.FechaModificacion,
            @UltimoSector = expediente.UltimoSector.Value,
            @Estado = expediente.Estado,
        };

        expediente.ExpedienteId = await conexion.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sql, parametrosExpediente);
        return expediente;
    }
}
```

The tests i perform was the following:

1- execute the query from sql : *success without errors*
2- Try the solutions of these stackoverflow cases

[Get the id of inserted row using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405910/get-the-id-of-inserted-row-using-c-sharp)
[is there an ExecuteScalar in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050636/is-there-an-executescalar-in-dapper)
[Getting an sqlException when I run ExecuteScalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076322/getting-an-sqlexception-when-i-run-executescalar)

3- console log from front: *success without errors*
4- window immediately before line 154: *success no error*

I thank you for your time!!

- Edited with the clean passed code
- the expedienteId is not auto-incremental, therefore it does not use IDENTITY, it is just an id that the user puts without respecting an order if he wanted to.
- try to use `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` but the IdbConnection doesn't recognize it

Comment: Since you are explicitly setting a value for `ExpedienteId`, I very much doubt it's an `IDENTITY`, and so `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` isn't going to work. It's unclear what you are hoping to achieve with this code -- if the ID should be assigned by the database you shouldn't be inserting it, and if it's assigned by you you don't need to ask the DB for it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ...  I already took the SCOPE_IDENTITY() from the query... the idea of ​​the post is to insert the data "by hand", send it to the database and then with a GET recover it as it was inserted... it is a basic exercise that it fails for some reason i don't see

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question with the code as it looks right now then, and while you're at it replace your screenshot with actual code. The basics remain the same: either you are performing an `INSERT` where you pass the ID, and then you should *neither* use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` *nor* `.ExecuteScalarAsync()` (just use `.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` and *don't* assign the property); *or* you are relying on an `IDENTITY`, but then you should not (cannot) pass the `ID` in the `INSERT` because it will be auto-assigned.

Comment: What would you expect that `ExecuteScalar` return for an `INSERT`? Why are you assigning this result (seemingly `0`) to your Id?

Comment: before ... ExecuteScalar (line 154) the FileId comes a real data.. when passing through the ExecuteScalar the id becomes 0

Comment: `INSERT` returns no value. `ExecuteScalar` gives you the default value for `int`. You assign this value to your property. ...where does the mystery come in? What do you *want* the database to do -- give you back the same value you just inserted, so you can assign the property to the value it already has? What purpose does that serve? This dance with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `ExecuteScalar` makes sense if the database is the one assigning the ID, because then you don't know it in advance -- but here, you do.